# detect different vales in same id

Tags: r

I have an easy question. I want to mutate a new column as shown below.

```
DF<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,3),code=c("1","0","1","0","0"))
> DF
  id code
1  1    1
2  1    0
3  2    1
4  3    0
5  3    0
```

Desired output:

```
id code type
1  1    1  mix
2  1    0  mix
3  2    1    A
4  3    0    B
5  3    0    B
```

Anyone eager to help?

Comment: Please explain in words the logic to generate the `type` column.

Comment: Yes, sorry a bit vague. Persons are grouped by id The type column should reflect if a person (same id) has just 1 or 0 or both 1 and 0 in code. Hope its clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe setting up conditions in `case_when` is what you are looking for.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(type = case_when(n_distinct(code) > 1 ~ 'mix', 
                          all(code == 1) ~ 'A', 
                          all(code == 0) ~ 'B')) %>%
  ungroup

#     id code  type 
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#1     1 1     mix  
#2     1 0     mix  
#3     2 1     A    
#4     3 0     B    
#5     3 0     B
```

Comment: Thanks alot Ronak.I think it was n_distinct and all I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

**tidyverse**

```r
library(tidyverse)
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,3),code=c("1","0","1","0","0"))

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(type = if_else(
    n_distinct(code) > 1,
    true = 99999,
    false = as.numeric(cur_group_id())
  )) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(type = if_else(type == 99999, true = "mix", false = LETTERS[type - min(type) + 1]))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>      id code  type 
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 1     mix  
#> 2     1 0     mix  
#> 3     2 1     A    
#> 4     3 0     B    
#> 5     3 0     B
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**data.table**

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,3),code=c("1","0","1","0","0"))
setDT(df)[, type := fifelse(test = uniqueN(code) > 1, yes = 99999, no = .GRP - 1), by = id] %>% 
  .[, type := fifelse(test = type == 99999, yes = "mix", no = LETTERS[as.numeric(type)])] %>% 
  .[]
#>    id code type
#> 1:  1    1  mix
#> 2:  1    0  mix
#> 3:  2    1    A
#> 4:  3    0    B
#> 5:  3    0    B
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(type = setNames(c('A', 'B', 'mix'), c(1, 0, 
      2))[as.character(replace(code, n_distinct(code)> 1, 2))]) %>%
   ungroup
# A tibble: 5 × 3
     id code  type 
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1 1     mix  
2     1 0     mix  
3     2 1     A    
4     3 0     B    
5     3 0     B
```